# In Illustrator, is it possible to close a shape with fill automatically after drawing?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud, adobe-freehand

Like Freehand had, is it possible to draw a shape without a fill or stroke and then when the shape has been closed/completed, the fill would automatically be applied?

Answer (score 1):

If having the fill on when you are plotting your path bothers you, you could always hop into Outline mode (CTRL + Y, or CMD + Y if you're on a Mac) to see paths only, and then hop out when you're done with your shape.

Answer (score 0):

Just draw the shape with no fill and stroke. When you finish the path, press V. Deselect the shape and then reselect the shape. Now add a fill or stroke.

I am not sure of any automatic function that adds a full after you complete a path.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify the significance of the fill being applied *automatically*?

Before starting the path, select "none" for both fill and path. After closing your path, simply select the fill color in the same box or any required swatch/pattern.

[image: [1]]

Answer (score 0):

Choose the pen or shape tool and then select the fill and/or stroke colors you'd like, then draw and close. It will default to the colors selected. And as mentioned in this thread, you can just change those colors at will by choosing the selection tool and selecting the shape. Not sure if there is something I am not understanding.